# Selecting an option from dropdown that opens up when clicked and mouse hover

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium and Python to click on a dropdown button (id = "export") and then select the option (id = "downloadCSV") when it opens up, but the dropdown list disappears when mouse is not hovering on it.

here's the html:

```
<div class="actionsButton actionsDD" id="export">
                <span class="actionsLabel">Download</span>
                <ul class="actionsDDsub">
                    <li><span id="downloadCSV">CSV</span></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="actionsArrow"></div>
</div>
```

here's the code I'm trying:

```
export=driver.find_element_by_id('export')
download=driver.find_element_by_id('downloadCSV')
actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(export)
actions.click(export)
actions.click(download)
actions.perform()
```

I think the problem is that after click on the dropdown button the mouse does not stay hovering on the button. I need to click and at the same time keep the mouse on there, to be able to click on the option.

Please help how to achieve this. Much appreicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you. Try to hover again back to button and then perform click action

```
actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.Id, 'export'))))
actions.click(export)
actions.move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.Id, 'downloadCSV'))))// if you get elemeent not found exception then try to move_to_element to 'export' first and then click on download
actions.click(download)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

The drop down menu may still be there, just hidden.  Try pressing f12 while on the page, your dev tools should pop up.  If your on Chrome look for the tab that says 'Elements' to view the computed source code of the web page.  Firefox also has a builtin dev tools.  Its' options should be pretty self explanatory, but here I'll cover Chromes'.

All the way to the left you'll find an arrow in a box.  Click it to sync the source view with the page elements so as you move your mouse over the page it shows the code in the 'Elements' window.  Move the mouse over the menu to see it's code.

However the menu, most likely, will not drop down while in this mode when you hover.  You will have to investigate the source after clicking on the element you want to view, you can dynamically change it's css (or html).  Your changes will remain until you refresh the page.  Instead of having selenium 'hover', just grab the element you want like so: driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).  The Seleniums' documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/

Grab the href value of the [duh](https://somepage.com) tags if you just need to follow the link.  But if you need to click the link try this:
driver.findElement(By.linkText("See an example alert")).click();

In this case you would just have too know the text between the TEXT tags.  If this doesn't work try making the menu visible using selenium before clicking.  To make it visible look through the source to see if display is none on the menu.  If it is then make it something like block or inline then try again.

If you still have problems poke around in the 'Sources' tab in dev tools.  You can search for element tags in the javascript, and there's also a debug function to step through the code to see what javascript is doing when you hover.  You basically just need to make the element visible to selenium before you click, that is if the previous solutions don't work.  Hope this helps.